# Backbone events not firing on new element added to DOM

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I'm using a combination of handlebars and Backbone. I have one "container" view which has an array to hold child views. Whenever I add a new view, click events are not being bound.

My Post View:

```
Post.View = Backbone.View.extend({
    CommentViews: {},
    events: {
        "click .likePost": "likePost",
        "click .dislikePost": "dislikePost",
        "click .addComment button": "addComment"
    },
    render: function() {
        this.model.set("likeCount", this.model.get("likes").length);
        this.model.set("dislikeCount", this.model.get("dislikes").length);
        this.$('.like-count').html(this.model.get("likeCount") + " likes");
        this.$('.dislike-count').html(this.model.get("dislikeCount") + " dislikes");

        return this;
    }, ...
```

My callback code in the "container" view which creates a new backbone view, attaches it to a handlebars template and shows it on the page:

```
success: _.bind(function(data,status,xhr) {
                        $(this.el).find("#appendedInputButton").val('');
                        var newPost = new Post.Model(data);
                        var newPostView = new Post.View({model: newPost, el: "#wall-post-" + newPost.id});
                        var source = $("#post-template").html();
                        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

                        var html = template(newPost.toJSON());
                        this.$('#posts').append(html);
                        newPostView.render();
                        this.PostViews[newPost.id] = newPostView;
                    }, this), ...
```

Not sure what's going on, but this sort of code is run initially to set up the page (sans handlebars since the html is rendered server-side) and all events work fine. If I reload the page, I can like/dislike a post as well.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I dont see you appending `newPostView.render().el` to dom .Or am i missing somehting?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the "#post-template" contains the "likePost" button. The newPostView is never added to the DOM.

Adding el to the new Post.View makes backbone search the DOM (and the element won't exist yet)
4 lines later a HTML string is added to the DOM (assuming the this.el is already in the DOM)

If you create the Post.View after the append(html) the element can be found and events would be fireing.
But the natural Backbone way would be to render the HTML string inside the Post.View render function, append the result to it's el and append that el to the #posts element.

```
success: function (data) {
  var view = new Post.View({model: new Post.Model(data)});
  this.$('#posts').append(view.render().el);
  this.PostViews[data.id] = view;
}
```